# which file can i find the woocommerce Store notice code

Tags: woocommerce, store, notice

Please can anyone help I want to edit the Function code for my Wordpress Woo Commerse Store Notice,

but I'm having troble locating the `function demo_store_filter($text)` please could help me with the file name

Comment: Search for **`woocommerce_demo_store`** in your `functions.php` file. Find it in your active theme directory. Here you find the documentation: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.1056

Comment: If you don't want to do it from code: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-customizer/